# Can i set different orientations for IPad and IPhone (Universal) app in cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a cordova app for both Ipad and Iphone and i need the iphone app to support only for portrait and ipad app to support only for landscape. Right now i have set `<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />` in the config.xml file.This will only set the orientation for iphone. Is there anyway i can set the ipad orientation from the config file within doing anything in the ios project after the build.

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782224/universal-application-with-portrait-orientation-for-iphone-and-landscape-orienta

Comment: I want this to be configured within cordova config.xml not from the ios project

Comment: How is this STILL an open issue/challenge for Cordova! The "custom plugin" solution doesn't work or is quirky as you can't install it easily via "cordova plugin add" and the after_prepare hook keeps giving me EACCES errors. Argh!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cordova doesn't support this out-of-the-box, but you can use a hook during the build process to insert code into the iOS plist, to save to having to manually edit it after the project build.

The following solution is based on a post by [@djett](http://forum.ionicframework.com/users/djett) on [this page](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/config-xml-preference-orientation-not-working-for-ios/6050/9). However, note that there's currently [a bug in the Cordova 5.0.0 CLI](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8953) which is causing custom iOS orientation settings to be wiped out during the build process.

In your config xml, add:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>          
        </array>
    </config-file>
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

And add the following code [from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/master/templates/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js) to {your_project}/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/** This hook updates platform configuration files based on preferences and config-file data defined in config.xml.
    Currently only the AndroidManifest.xml and IOS *-Info.plist file are supported.

    Preferences:
    1.  Preferences defined outside of the platform element will apply to all platforms
    2.  Preferences defined inside a platform element will apply only to the specified platform
    3.  Platform preferences take precedence over common preferences
    4.  The preferenceMappingData object contains all of the possible custom preferences to date including the
        target file they belong to, parent element, and destination element or attribute

    Config Files
    1.  config-file elements MUST be defined inside a platform element, otherwise they will be ignored.
    2.  config-file target attributes specify the target file to update. (AndroidManifest.xml or *-Info.plist)
    3.  config-file parent attributes specify the parent element (AndroidManifest.xml) or parent key (*-Info.plist)
        that the child data will replace or be appended to.
    4.  config-file elements are uniquely indexed by target AND parent for each platform.
    5.  If there are multiple config-file's defined with the same target AND parent, the last config-file will be used
    6.  Elements defined WITHIN a config-file will replace or be appended to the same elements relative to the parent element
    7.  If a unique config-file contains multiples of the same elements (other than uses-permssion elements which are
        selected by by the uses-permission name attribute), the last defined element will be retrieved.

    Examples:

    AndroidManifest.xml
    NOTE: For possible manifest values see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

    <platform name="android">
        //These preferences are actually available in Cordova by default although not currently documented
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
        <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="19" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />

        //custom preferences examples
        <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible" />
        <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <preference name="android-launchMode" value="singleTop" />
        <preference name="android-activity-hardwareAccelerated" value="false" />
        <preference name="android-manifest-hardwareAccelerated" value="false" />
        <preference name="android-configChanges" value="orientation" />
        <preference name="android-theme" value="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />

        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*>
            <supports-screens
                android:xlargeScreens="false"
                android:largeScreens="false"
                android:smallScreens="false" />

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:maxSdkVersion="15" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>

    *-Info.plist

    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeOmg</string>
            </array>
        </config-file>

        <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="SomeOtherPlistKey">
            <string>someValue</string>
        </config-file>
    </platform>

    NOTE: Currently, items aren't removed from the platform config files if you remove them from config.xml.
          For example, if you add a custom permission, build the remove it, it will still be in the manifest.
          If you make a mistake, for example adding an element to the wrong parent, you may need to remove and add your platform,
          or revert to your previous manifest/plist file.

    TODO: We may need to capture all default manifest/plist elements/keys created by Cordova along with any plugin elements/keys to compare against custom elements to remove.
 */

// global vars
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');
var et = require('elementtree');
var plist = require('plist');

var rootdir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');

var platformConfig = (function(){
    /*  Global object that defines the available custom preferences for each platform.
     Maps a config.xml preference to a specific target file, parent element, and destination attribute or element
     */
    var preferenceMappingData = {
        'android': {
            'android-manifest-hardwareAccelerated': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: './', destination: 'android:hardwareAccelerated'},
            'android-installLocation': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: './', destination: 'android:installLocation'},
            'android-activity-hardwareAccelerated': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: 'application', destination: 'android:hardwareAccelerated'},
            'android-configChanges': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: 'application/activity[@android:name=\'CordovaApp\']', destination: 'android:configChanges'},
            'android-launchMode': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: 'application/activity[@android:name=\'CordovaApp\']', destination: 'android:launchMode'},
            'android-theme': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: 'application/activity[@android:name=\'CordovaApp\']', destination: 'android:theme'},
            'android-windowSoftInputMode': {target: 'AndroidManifest.xml', parent: 'application/activity[@android:name=\'CordovaApp\']', destination: 'android:windowSoftInputMode'}
        },
        'ios': {}
    };
    var configXmlData, preferencesData;

    return {
        // Parses a given file into an elementtree object
        parseElementtreeSync: function (filename) {
            var contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8');
            if(contents) {
                //Windows is the BOM. Skip the Byte Order Mark.
                contents = contents.substring(contents.indexOf('<'));
            }
            return new et.ElementTree(et.XML(contents));
        },

        // Converts an elementtree object to an xml string.  Since this is used for plist values, we don't care about attributes
        eltreeToXmlString: function (data) {
            var tag = data.tag;
            var el = '<' + tag + '>';

            if(data.text && data.text.trim()) {
                el += data.text.trim();
            } else {
                _.each(data.getchildren(), function (child) {
                    el += platformConfig.eltreeToXmlString(child);
                });
            }

            el += '</' + tag + '>';
            return el;
        },

        // Parses the config.xml into an elementtree object and stores in the config object
        getConfigXml: function () {
            if(!configXmlData) {
                configXmlData = this.parseElementtreeSync(path.join(rootdir, 'config.xml'));
            }

            return configXmlData;
        },

        /* Retrieves all <preferences ..> from config.xml and returns a map of preferences with platform as the key.
           If a platform is supplied, common prefs + platform prefs will be returned, otherwise just common prefs are returned.
         */
        getPreferences: function (platform) {
            var configXml = this.getConfigXml();

            //init common config.xml prefs if we haven't already
            if(!preferencesData) {
                preferencesData = {
                    common: configXml.findall('preference')
                };
            }

            var prefs = preferencesData.common || [];
            if(platform) {
                if(!preferencesData[platform]) {
                    preferencesData[platform] = configXml.findall('platform[@name=\'' + platform + '\']/preference');
                }
                prefs = prefs.concat(preferencesData[platform]);
            }

            return prefs;
        },

        /* Retrieves all configured xml for a specific platform/target/parent element nested inside a platforms config-file
           element within the config.xml.  The config-file elements are then indexed by target|parent so if there are
           any config-file elements per platform that have the same target and parent, the last config-file element is used.
         */
        getConfigFilesByTargetAndParent: function (platform) {
            var configFileData = this.getConfigXml().findall('platform[@name=\'' + platform + '\']/config-file');

            return  _.indexBy(configFileData, function(item) {
                var parent = item.attrib.parent;
                //if parent attribute is undefined /* or */, set parent to top level elementree selector
                if(!parent || parent === '/*' || parent === '*/') {
                    parent = './';
                }
                return item.attrib.target + '|' + parent;
            });
        },

        // Parses the config.xml's preferences and config-file elements for a given platform
        parseConfigXml: function (platform) {
            var configData = {};
            this.parsePreferences(configData, platform);
            this.parseConfigFiles(configData, platform);

            return configData;
        },

        // Retrieves the config.xml's pereferences for a given platform and parses them into JSON data
        parsePreferences: function (configData, platform) {
            var preferences = this.getPreferences(platform),
                type = 'preference';

            _.each(preferences, function (preference) {
                var prefMappingData = preferenceMappingData[platform][preference.attrib.name],
                    target,
                    prefData;

                if (prefMappingData) {
                    prefData = {
                        parent: prefMappingData.parent,
                        type: type,
                        destination: prefMappingData.destination,
                        data: preference
                    };

                    target = prefMappingData.target;
                    if(!configData[target]) {
                        configData[target] = [];
                    }
                    configData[target].push(prefData);
                }
            });
        },

        // Retrieves the config.xml's config-file elements for a given platform and parses them into JSON data
        parseConfigFiles: function (configData, platform) {
            var configFiles = this.getConfigFilesByTargetAndParent(platform),
                type = 'configFile';

            _.each(configFiles, function (configFile, key) {
                var keyParts = key.split('|');
                var target = keyParts[0];
                var parent = keyParts[1];
                var items = configData[target] || [];

                _.each(configFile.getchildren(), function (element) {
                    items.push({
                        parent: parent,
                        type: type,
                        destination: element.tag,
                        data: element
                    });
                });

                configData[target] = items;
            });
        },

        // Parses config.xml data, and update each target file for a specified platform
        updatePlatformConfig: function (platform) {
            var configData = this.parseConfigXml(platform),
                platformPath = path.join(rootdir, 'platforms', platform);

            _.each(configData, function (configItems, targetFileName) {
                var projectName, targetFile;

                if (platform === 'ios' && targetFileName.indexOf("Info.plist") > -1) {
                    projectName = platformConfig.getConfigXml().findtext('name');
                    targetFile = path.join(platformPath, projectName, projectName + '-Info.plist');
                    platformConfig.updateIosPlist(targetFile, configItems);
                } else if (platform === 'android' && targetFileName === 'AndroidManifest.xml') {
                    targetFile = path.join(platformPath, targetFileName);
                    platformConfig.updateAndroidManifest(targetFile, configItems);
                }
            });
        },

        // Updates the AndroidManifest.xml target file with data from config.xml
        updateAndroidManifest: function (targetFile, configItems) {
            var tempManifest = platformConfig.parseElementtreeSync(targetFile),
                root = tempManifest.getroot();

            _.each(configItems, function (item) {
                // if parent is not found on the root, child/grandchild nodes are searched
                var parentEl = root.find(item.parent) || root.find('*/' + item.parent),
                    data = item.data,
                    childSelector = item.destination,
                    childEl;

                if(!parentEl) {
                    return;
                }

                if(item.type === 'preference') {
                    parentEl.attrib[childSelector] = data.attrib['value'];
                } else {
                    // since there can be multiple uses-permission elements, we need to select them by unique name
                    if(childSelector === 'uses-permission') {
                        childSelector += '[@android:name=\'' + data.attrib['android:name'] + '\']';
                    }

                    childEl = parentEl.find(childSelector);
                    // if child element doesnt exist, create new element
                    if(!childEl) {
                        childEl = new et.Element(item.destination);
                        parentEl.append(childEl);
                    }

                    // copy all config.xml data except for the generated _id property
                    _.each(data, function (prop, propName) {
                        if(propName !== '_id') {
                            childEl[propName] = prop;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, tempManifest.write({indent: 4}), 'utf-8');
        },

        /* Updates the *-Info.plist file with data from config.xml by parsing to an xml string, then using the plist
           module to convert the data to a map.  The config.xml data is then replaced or appended to the original plist file
         */
        updateIosPlist: function (targetFile, configItems) {
            var infoPlist = plist.parse(fs.readFileSync(targetFile, 'utf-8')),
                tempInfoPlist;

            _.each(configItems, function (item) {
                var key = item.parent;
                var plistXml = '<plist><dict><key>' + key + '</key>';
                plistXml += platformConfig.eltreeToXmlString(item.data) + '</dict></plist>';

                var configPlistObj = plist.parse(plistXml);
                infoPlist[key] = configPlistObj[key];
            });

            tempInfoPlist = plist.build(infoPlist);
            tempInfoPlist = tempInfoPlist.replace(/<string>[\s\r\n]*<\/string>/g,'<string></string>');
            fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, tempInfoPlist, 'utf-8');
        }
    };
})();

// Main
(function () {
    if (rootdir) {
        // go through each of the platform directories that have been prepared
        var platforms = _.filter(fs.readdirSync('platforms'), function (file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.resolve('platforms', file)).isDirectory();
        });

        _.each(platforms, function (platform) {
            try {
                platform = platform.trim().toLowerCase();
                platformConfig.updatePlatformConfig(platform);
            } catch (e) {
                process.stdout.write(e);
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to update my orientation via the config as it was always a manual task setting it on build day. I have since added this plugin:

[Cordova-Custom-Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config)

I was then able to add these to my config and didn't have to worry about it again.

```
<platform name="ios">
   <!-- Set orientation on iPhone -->
   <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
     <array>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
     </array>
   </config-file>
   <!-- Set orientation on iPad -->
   <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad">
     <array>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
       <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
     </array>
   </config-file>
</platform>
```

I also use this plugin: 
[Cordova-Screen-Orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation)
Very flexible and greater control, allowing you to specify orientation lockdown on specific devices (xs,sm,md,lg), specific platforms and different pages, ie. if your app is all portrait but when you go to video page you want them to be in landscape.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I could not get this to work with [edit-config](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) and Cordova 7, but I could get this working with the [cordova-custom-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config#ios) plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config --save
```

Then add the following to config.xml. Note the `custom-config-file` elements for version 5 of this plugin instead of the `config-file` elements, to prevent [conflicting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config#changes-in-cordova-custom-config5) with cordova parsing the `config-file` elements.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <custom-config-file mode="replace" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" target="*-Info.plist">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        </array>
    </custom-config-file>
    <custom-config-file mode="replace" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad" target="*-Info.plist">
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
    </custom-config-file>
    ...
</platform>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with "edit-config" nor "config-file" but your solution worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS Cordova application you can use cordova-custom-config plugin, which is very easy to use and requires changes only in config.xml.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config#ios-example

Answer (score -1):

May be try enclosing the orientation for different device in the following way - (But have not checked whether that will work, just a wild clue)

```
<platform name="iPhone">
        <preference name="" value="" />
 </platform>
<platform name="iPad">
        <preference name="" value="" />
 </platform>
```

Comment: Then only option is to write the code in the iOS project, as stated above