# How to disable landscape mode for iPod users within Cordova app?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, landscape-portrait

I have a React app running inside a Cordova wrapper and want to disable landscape mode for only iPod users. Does anyone know how to do this? I'm assuming I need to add something within `config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set preference in your `config.xml`.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Comment: But how can I do this just for iPod users?

Comment: Cordova doesn't support this out-of-the-box, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497799/can-i-set-different-orientations-for-ipad-and-iphone-universal-app-in-cordova)